# How to save the DATE & TIME as yyyymmdd & hhmmss in a file

Tags: vb.net, date, datagridview, datepicker, hl7

In this code am saving the data in a file and where the `Examdate`, `Examtime` and `DOB` are saving as ex: 03:15 PM and i want them as 1515 (with seconds, too). I have no idea how to do?

```
Private Sub HL_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles HL.Click
        Dim file As System.IO.StreamWriter
        Dim fileDateTime As String = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd") & "_" & DateTime.Now.ToString("HHmmss")
        file = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileWriter(fileDateTime, True)
            file.WriteLine("MSH|^~\&|||||" & TxtExamtime.Text & "||ORM^O01||P|2.3.1")
            file.WriteLine("PID|||" & TxtId.Text & "||" & TxtFamilyname.Text & "^" & TxtGivenname.Text & "||" & TxtDob.Text & "||" & TxtGender.Text & "|||" & TxtStreet.Text & " " & TxtHouse.Text & "^^" & TxtCity.Text & "^^" & TxtPostcode.Text)
            file.WriteLine("PV1||O|||||||||||||||||" & TxtId.Text & "|||||||||||||||||||||||||" & TxtExamdate.Text)
            file.WriteLine("ORC|NW|" & TxtId.Text & "|||||^^^" & TxtExamdate.Text & "||" & TxtExamdate.Text)
            file.WriteLine("OBR||" & TxtExamdate.Text & TxtExamdate.Text & "||CT|||" & TxtExamtime.Text & "|" & TxtExamtime.Text)
            file.WriteLine()

        file.Close()
        MessageBox.Show("Textsaved to " & fileDateTime)
    End Sub
```

Comment: You'll have to convert your textbox to DateTime if you want to start doing any manipulations.

Answer (score 1):

Since it looks like you're dealing with a text value rather than a date, you'll have to cast it as a `DateTime` variable and then back into the format you want. Example:

`DateTime.Parse(txtExamtime.Text).ToString("HHmmss")`